# discord.py | how to get date of the command getting invoked

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I wanna know how can I get the date when the command was invoked, I know how to get time by using `datetime.datetime` but idk how to get date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you almost answered your own question. `datetime.datetime` gives you even more options.

**Have a look at the following code**, here wrapped as a command:

```py
@client.command() / @bot.command() / @commands.command()
async def time(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"It is: {datetime.datetime.now()}") # Your timezone
    await ctx.send(f"It is: {datetime.datetime.utcnow()}") # UTC time
```

**Both output the following:**

```py
It is: 2021-05-26 19:14:32.793941 # Your timezone
It is: 2021-05-26 17:14:33.024169 # UTC time
```

With this information you should be able to query when a command was used.